# Monitor internet applications usage vb.net

Tags: vb.net, access-point

I have a windows 8 computer that i use as an access point using [connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) as the hotspot software. I want to control my clients by blocking and allowing some of their applications, such as skype or any other applications accessing the Internet. I wanted to know if there is a way i can do it using vb.net - something like blocking applications by application name.

Comment: Better use a 3rd party software. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Neolisk can u suggest the wheel?

Comment: I wanted to do this because i wanted it to configure automatically when demand has changed i.e high or low.

Comment: If you better describe what you want, I could certainly suggest a suitable wheel for it. Some examples: Kerio Firewall (used to be called like that), cFosSpeed - if you just want to auto-shape traffic, so nobody takes whole channel for themselves. Another auto-shaping mechanism is using a DD-WRT router - you can set traffic priorities there.

Comment: More examples: [NetSpeedMonitor](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57488792-285/monitor-your-pc-bandwidth-usage-with-netspeedmonitor/) and [DUMeter](http://www.hageltech.com/dumeter/about) - found by googling. [CCProxy](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/) - "Powerful Internet Access Control Software".